# Should we make "exoplanets" and "planets" synonyms?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

I just removed the [exoplanets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exoplanets) tag from [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14312/what-would-the-conditions-on-a-methane-world-be-like), which clearly just needed the [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets) tag. The [exoplanets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exoplanets) tag is still used on [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14066/youve-made-it-to-another-star-now-how-do-you-find-its-planets), which involves arriving in another planetary system, viewing the planets as exoplanets, as opposed to planets in viewer's original system.

Do we need the [exoplanets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exoplanets) tag, or should it be made a synonym of [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets)?

I'm in favor of this, because I can't see many questions needing to differentiate between planets and exoplanets.

Besides, exoplanets are just planets that aren't near where you are. It's similar to the idea that ever person is a foreigner - to someone else.

Comment: In favour. I can't see a need for both either.

Comment: If we have an exo-planets tag, shouldn't we have an exo-stars tag, or an exo-moons tag, and so on? It seems like a slippery slope, and thus should be destroyed before it grows too powerful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it could be argued that exo-planets is not needed at all.  The difference is all in perspective, and if that perspective is not evident in the question I would hazard a guess that the question isn't great in the first place.  I would be fine with removing or making them synonyms.

Comment: A synonym between "planets" and "exoplanets" should not be required; autocompletion should suffice in that case.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling well since both tags have appeared that's not what has happened...

Answer (score 2):

I agree, and since others seem to as well I've made this change.

Comment: IMO there is no need to have "exoplanets" as a synonym to "planets".

Answer (score 1):

An exoplanet is just like a planet except that it's in another solar system. Using the tag would make sense only (maybe) if it was using the in-world perspective. We would be talking about a far away planet vs the planets we can see with naked eyes/affordable telescopes.

Other than that, as James already mentioned, it's just a matter of perspective. From the omniscient point of view, the differentiation doesn't add anything.